# Свой шаблон для терминов и архива. Как реализовать?

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет!

Создал шаблон для терминов таксономий и архива типа записи. Шаблон единый и выводит список постов.
Подключил следующим образом:

```
function get_list_tax_page_template( $list_tax_page_template ) {

    if ( is_tax( 'myTax1', 'myTax2'  ) ) {
        $list_tax_page_template = TEMPLATEPATH.'/list-page.php';
    }
    return $list_tax_page_template;
}
add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', 'get_list_tax_page_template' );
```

Все работает, шаблон для указанных таксономий подключается.

Далее подключаю тот же шаблон для архива:

```
    function get_list_archive_page_template( $list_archive_page_template ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'myCustomPostType' ) ) {
        $list_archive_page_template = TEMPLATEPATH.'/list-page.php';
    }
    return $list_archive_page_template;
}
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'get_list_archive_page_template' );
```

Все работает, шаблон для указанного типа записи подключается.

Дальше стопор...
Каким образом управлять этим шаблоном через админку? По типу как со страницей (редактировать заголовок, текст, SEO-дела прописать тем же WordPress SEO by Yoast)... В общем, не понимаю, как действовать дальше.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, научите.

Comment: Не до конца понимаю, что ты делаешь
По идеи, у тебя есть php шаблон, где ты можешь писать все, что душе угодно и тип записей, который в этот шаблон подгружается - для каждой записи данного типа (или с данной таксономий) ты можешь задавать свой заголовок, контент и т.п. Что ты пытаешься добиться от "управления шаблоном через админку"?  Я чего-то не понимаю...

Answer (score 1):

Так если установить WP SEO, то в админке и так соотв. поля для мета и т.п. на странице правки категории добавятся, а в шаблоне выводить - просто так же как и в стандартном шаблоне.

P.S. не совсем понятно для чего так мудрить с шаблонами - WP  и сам умеет их находить, просто [правильно](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) нужно файл с шаблоном назвать.